# How i can change my splash screen with zsh terminal?

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, lts, zsh

Guys I install a bad splash screen and my KDE desktop is broke and not loud bet I have access to my terminal so I want to change my splash screen by terminal maybe my problem is fixed

I use Kubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

The KDE splash screen configuration is stored in:-

```
/usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/lockscreen/LockScreen.qml
```

My suggestion is your custom image directory create a symlink to a real image file then all you have to do is change the symlink to a different file.

Example assuming you configure KDE to use ~/images/kde_splash.png

e.g.

```
ln -sf ~/images/batman_logo.png ~/images/kde_splash.png
```

or

```
ln -sf ~/images/superman_logo.png ~/images/kde_splash.png
```

Which means whenever KDE reads ~/images/kde_splash.png it will reference the file you have chosen.